# Why is kriging using parallel processing still using memory and not using my processors?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, kriging, gstat

I have a large dataset of measurement over an area. I want to interpolate my data using kriging over my study area. My final output should be a raster/grid. 
My pc has 8Gb RAM and 4 cores. When I try to use predict() with my fitted variogram, my memory is full and my pc does not respond anymore. I have the possibility to run my code on multiple cores (over 20!) but my code needs to be tidy and working on a smaller subset on my personal laptop before I can use it on my whole dataset on a super computer.

I tried to parallelize the predict() function using the parallel package following the script provided by Guzmán to answer the question [How to achieve parallel Kriging in R to speed up the process?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237672/how-to-achieve-parallel-kriging-in-r-to-speed-up-the-process). However, I have the same problem as before with my memory being used to the max and my processors not being used. 
I have tried to reduce my dataset of fewer data points and smaller grid, to test my code, but it still did not work (using all the memory and taking for ever to compute).

My data is a SpatialPointsDataFrame with some measurements of Cu(ppm).

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(gstat)

# Data
head(sp.soil)

#   NAT_North NAT_East  NAT_RL Cu_ppm
# 1:   6281361 376058.9 1213.06     56
# 2:   6281545 376020.8 1211.19     52
# 3:   6281408 376073.1 1235.29    110
# 4:   6281326 376078.0 1225.85    116
# 5:   6281312 376122.3 1227.95     26
# 6:   6281302 376160.3 1231.50     60

# Grid
grd <- GridTopology(cellcentre.offset = c(box[1,1], box[2,1]),
                    cellsize = c(100,100),
                    cells.dim = c(15,12)) 
grd <- SpatialGrid(grd,
                   proj4string = proj)

## KRIGING
# Experimental semi-variogram
v.Cu <- variogram(gstat(formula = log10(Cu_ppm) ~ 1, data = sp.soil))

# Fit variogram model
fit.v.Cu <- fit.variogram(object = v.Cu, model = vgm(c("Sph","Exp")))

# Define the fitted geostatistical model
k.Cu <- gstat(formula = log10(Cu_ppm) ~ 1, data = sp.soil, model = fit.v.Cu) 

# Parallelization
library(parallel)

no_cores <- detectCores() - 1 

# Initiate cluster
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)

parts.x <- split(1:grd@grid@cells.dim[2], f = 1:no_cores-1)
parts.y <- split(1:grd@grid@cells.dim[1], f = 1:no_cores-1)

clusterExport(cl = cl, varlist = c("grd", "k.Cu", "parts.x", "parts.y"), envir = .GlobalEnv)
clusterEvalQ(cl = cl, expr = c(library('sp'), library('gstat')))

parallelX <- parLapply(cl = cl,
                       X = 1:no_cores,
                       fun = function(x) predict(k.Cu, grd[parts.x[[x]], parts.y[[x]] ]) )

stopCluster(cl)

mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(parallelX[[1]], parallelX[[2]])
mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(mergeParallelX, parallelX[[3]])
```

I just don't see where the error could be coming from. I have used Guzman code as it is, so why is it not working? Any hints?